# Sql warning message retrieve using peta poco ORM

Tags: asp.net-mvc, petapoco

We have feature that create tables dynamically, While creating table I am getting following warning message:

> Warning: The table "@@workingData" has been created, but its maximum
>   row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes. INSERT or UPDATE
>   to this table will fail if the resulting row exceeds the size limit.

I need to notify this message to users.

Is any way to do this? I am using MVC and Peta Poco ORM

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of an underlying DB restriction. It says so here `The table "@@workingData" has been created, but its maximum row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes`.

I guess the how you notify users will be dependant on how this warning is presented. If an exception is thrown, that maybe easy. However, as the warning says the `table has been created`, it may be a situation where it works but you would prefer it didn't.

My recommendation is to calculate whether the users interaction will cause an error before executing the SQL against the database.

*Happy PetaPoco'er'ing*